# OpenMP: Assign threads one iteration at a time

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Say you have a loop containing a varying number of iterations and 4 cores

I understand that

`#pragma omp parallel for`

will basically divide the iterations in like this with chunks of size/4 length

`|    T1    |    T2     |     T3     |     T4     |`

However, in my particular situation, this behavior would be more advantageous.  Where each chunk is size/size length.  So thread 1 would not get iterations 0..size/4, but instead iterations 0,size/4,2*size/4,3*size/4

`|T1|T2|T3|T4|T1|T2|T3|T4|T1|T2|T3|T4|T1|T2|T3|T4|`

How can I have my code execute like this when the number of iterations is not known until runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing -- assuming that your heuristic is size/total threads -- is a round-robin scheduling (*i.e.,* static scheduling) with chunk_size = 1. For that you simply need :

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
```

In this case, it makes no difference if the number of iterations is known (or not) at runtime.